# Mismatched input Error using Case statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 cte's and I am trying to extract some data.

```
with first_cte as
(
  select * from table 
  where category in ("women","girls","cloth")
),
second_cte as 
(
  select *, case when upper(product_type)="BED" and upper(gender)="MALE" THEN "Male"
  when upper(product_type)="BED" and upper(gender)="FEMALE" THEN "Female"
  when upper(product_type)="BED" and upper(gender)="UNISEX" THEN "Unisex"
  else "Not defined"
  end as suggestion from first_cte
)
Select *, row_number() over(partition by suggestion order by suggestion) as row_num from second_cte;
```

While executing this query I get an error: mismatched input 'upper' expecting ')' (line 8)

I am not sure why this is happening since the syntax seems fine to me. Please assist me on the same. I am using MySQL.

I have tried removing the second CTE and instead using it in a "FROM" but that does not help. Also, I have tried to work around with parenthesis but have found no luck.

Comment: For starters, you're missing a comma after the first CTE. Next, your case expression is not valid. If you want them all to be one column, then use `case` just once. Don't repeat case. Should be `case when ... then... when... then... when... then... else... end`.

Comment: @Isolated wrote that by mistake, i've edited the question now.

Comment: So are you still getting an error when making those fixes? You still have `case` written more than once.

Comment: @Isolated yes, the issue still persists.

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors. Are you perhaps using an older version of MySQL? `row_number()` is not supported until Version 8. Remove that and try again. Then determine how to emulate row number. If using an older version, see [emulate row number](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

Comment: @Isolated, I have tried removing that and tried, but I still have the same error. I am confused with what to do.

Comment: MySql 5 also does not support CTE. First confirm this works: `select *, your case expression from your_table where category in ("women....")` Once you confirm that works, then determine how to emulate the row number by partition, which you can wrap around your query.

Comment: @isolated, I have tried all of that, having one expression in my case does not produce an error but when I add multiple scenarios, it gives me this error.